# How Do I Turn Off Google Now Card Notifications?

Tags: notifications, 4.2-jelly-bean, google-now

How do I turn off Google Card notifications?

Let's say I search for an address - Google will then show me a card in the notification area with driving directions to that location.  I don't want the notification.  Is there a way to prevent them from showing up?

Comment: Is this Google Now?

Comment: @wbogacz Yes, I believe so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this [help](http://support.google.com/android/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2677493), Google Now notifications can be limited or turned off.
*Most notifications for Google Now cards can be turned off or set to low or standard priority. Low priority notifications appear at the bottom of the notifications shade without any additional signal.

From the lower right corner of the Google Now screen, touch Menu > Settings > Google Now > card name > and adjust the settings under Notifications.*

Comment: Yes, that's it.  I actually chose to turn them off entirely.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on Jelly Bean and rooted you can use an app I built to manage notifications for all applications from a single place.

[Notifications Off](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aboutmycode.NotificationsOff) allows you to turn off notifications for all applications. It can also automatically disable notifications for new apps as soon as they are installed.

The next version will have support for profiles, tasker integration and a widget for switching profiles.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just start Google Settings (grey gear icon, with a g in the middle). Then choose Now Maps and switch off the top slider `show maps`. This will turn off the notifications as you wanted.